# Datatable did not display pagination and search when taken to script

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, datatable

I am uploading from excel using ASP.NET Core-6 MVC. I have this code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
{
    if (file == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    List<Students> studentList = new List<Student>();
    
    using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
        using(var package = new ExcelPackage(memoryStream))
        {
            var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
            if (worksheet.Dimension.Rows > 0 && worksheet.Dimension.Columns > 0)
            {
                for (int row = 2; row <= worksheet.Dimension.Rows; row++)   // start at row 2 to skip header
                {
                    Students student = new Students();
                    student.FirstName = worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value.ToString();
                    student.LastName = worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value.ToString();
                    student.AdmissionYear = int.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value.ToString());
                    student.RegistrationNo = worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value.ToString();
                    studentList.Add(student);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return View("Index", studentList);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<h2 class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">Convert Excel to HTML Table using JavaScript</h2>
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-header"><b>Select Excel File</b></div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="excel_file" />
            <input type="button" name="display" value="Show Data" id="btnShow" onclick="ShowData()" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
</div>
<div id="excel_data" class="mt-5"></div>
```

Since I am using a datatable, this is the script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonyous" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.15.1/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var table_output = "";
    var excel_file = document.getElementById("excel_file");
    excel_file.addEventListener("change",(event) =>{

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);

        reader.onload = function(event){
            var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);

            var work_book = XLSX.read(data,{type:'array'});

            var sheet_name = work_book.SheetNames;

            var sheet_data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(work_book.Sheets[sheet_name[0]],{hearder:1});
            
            if(sheet_data.length > 0)
            {
                var table_output = '<table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-bordered">';
                table_output += '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">';

                table_output += '<thead><tr><th>First Name </th><th> Last Name </th><th> AdmissionYear </th><th> RegistrationNo </th></tr></thead>';
                table_output += '<tbody>';

                for(var row = 0; row < sheet_data.length; row++)
                {
                    table_output += '<tr>';
                    table_output += '<td>' + sheet_data[row].FirstName + '</td>';
                    table_output += '<td>' + sheet_data[row].LastName + '</td>';
                    table_output += '<td>' + sheet_data[row].AdmissionYear + '</td>';
                    table_output += '<td>' + sheet_data[row].RegistrationNo + '</td>';
                    table_output += '</tr>';
                }

                table_output += '</tbody></table>';
            }
        }
    })
    function ShowData()
    {
        document.getElementById("excel_data").innerHTML = table_output;
    }
</script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#example1").DataTable({
            "responsive": true,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "autoWidth": false
        }).buttons().container().appendTo('#example1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
        $('#example2').DataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "searching": false,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "responsive": true,
        });
    });

    function checkAll(ele) {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        if (ele.checked) {
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                    checkboxes[i].checked = true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                console.log(i)
                if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                    checkboxes[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function checkSingle(ele) {
        var checkbox = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        console.log(ele.checked)
        if (ele.checked) {

            if (checkbox.type == 'checkbox') {
                checkbox.checked = false;
            }
        } else {
            checkbox.checked = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

As soon as the user choose the excel file to be uploaded, when he clicks on choose file, the application displays the excel data in the datatable html without even the submit upload button. This is okay

But where I'm having issue is that, the search and pagination on the datatable are not displayed. This was working before I added the excel script.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to generate the table  yourself,below codes aren't necessary:

```
var table_output = '<table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-bordered">';
                table_output += '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">';

                table_output += '<thead><tr><th>First Name </th><th> Last Name </th><th> AdmissionYear </th><th> RegistrationNo </th></tr></thead>';
                table_output += '<tbody>';

                for(var row = 0; row < sheet_data.length; row++)
                {
                    table_output += '<tr>';
                    table_output += '<td>' + sheet_data[row].FirstName + '</td>';
                    table_output += '<td>' + sheet_data[row].LastName + '</td>';
                    table_output += '<td>' + sheet_data[row].AdmissionYear + '</td>';
                    table_output += '<td>' + sheet_data[row].RegistrationNo + '</td>';
                    table_output += '</tr>';
                }

                table_output += '</tbody></table>';
```

you could create a 2Darray and modify your codes as below:

```
if (sheet_data.length > 0) {   
                    for (var row = 0; row < sheet_data.length; row++) {
                        //dt is a 2D array
                        dt.push([sheet_data[row].FirstName, sheet_data[row].LastName, sheet_data[row].AdmissionYear, sheet_data[row].RegistrationNo])                    
                    }
                }
```

and create the DataTable as below:

```
$(function () {
        $("#btnShow").click(function () {
            
            $('#example').DataTable({
                data: dt,
                columns: [
                    { title: 'FirstName' },
                    { title: 'LastName' },
                    { title: 'AdmissionYear' },
                    { title: 'ERegistrationNo' },
                    
                ],
            });
        });
    });
```

HtML codes：

```
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">Convert Excel to HTML Table using JavaScript</h2>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header"><b>Select Excel File</b></div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="excel_file" />
            <input type="button" name="display" value="Show Data" id="btnShow"  class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="excel_data" class="mt-5">
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>
</div>
```

The Result:

[image]